# Javascript - how to break and return to main function

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout, break

I am coding a javascript version of a matlab script. The Matlab code is composed of a `while` main loop in which I use `break` instructions into `if` conditions. I use too a sleep instruction between plotting instructions (to visualize the trajectory of a particle).

For my javascript version, from what I have seen on the web, I am trying to use `setTimeout` `clearTimeout` functions to simulate `sleep`.

Here what I have done :

```
function main() {
initGraphics();
button.onclick = function StartParticle() {
  drawPath();
  drawPathEnd();
};
}
```

with `drawPath()` function :

```
    function drawPath() {

    // Computing
    ...

    // Draw a segment

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo((x_begin*scale)+width/2, -(y_begin*scale)+height/2);
        ctx.lineTo((x_final*scale)+width/2, -(y_final*scale)+height/2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.stroke();

    // If conditions for breaking of this drawPath() function

    if ((((yt>4) && (t<4)) || ((yt>0) && (t>4))) && (delta_line>0))
            {direction='topright';
              clearTimeout(timer);
              return;}
            else if ((((yt>4) && (t>-4)) || ((yt>0) && (t<-4))) && (delta_line<0))
            {direction='topleft';
              clearTimeout(timer);
              return;}
            else if ((((yt<-4) && (t<4)) || ((yt<0) && (t>4)))  && (delta_line>0))
            {direction='bottomright';
              clearTimeout(timer);
              return;}
            else if ((((yt<-4) && (t>-4)) || ((yt<0) && (t<-4))) && (delta_line<0))
            {direction='bottomleft';
              clearTimeout(timer);
              return;}
          }

 // setTimeout for sleeping
    timer = setTimeout(function() {drawPath();}, 500);}
```

For example, in Matlab code, I used into `if conditions` for breaking the following thing :

```
while loop  

 %% Computing %%

 ...

  %% We draw a segment %%   
        vector1=[x_begin x_final];
        vector2=[y_begin y_final];
        line(vector1,vector2);

     %% Pause for animation %%
        pause(0.5);

%% if conditions for break %%

 if ((((yt>4) && (t<4)) || ((yt>0) && (t>4))) && (delta_line>0))
   direction='topright';
  break; 
  else if ((((yt>4) && (t>-4)) || ((yt>0) && (t<-4))) && (delta_line<0))
  direction='topleft';
  break;
  else if ((((yt<-4) && (t<4)) || ((yt<0) && (t>4)))  && (delta_line>0))
  direction='bottomright';
  break;
  else if ((((yt<-4) && (t>-4)) || ((yt<0) && (t<-4))) && (delta_line<0))
  direction='bottomleft';
  break;
  end
  end
  end
  end
  end  
end
```

But my problem is that, with `clearTimeout(timer);return;`, the code doesn't return to `main()` function : the function `drawPathEnd()` is not executed.

If anyone could tell me the right things to do in order to fix this,

Thanks

Comment: This comment is likely the source of your problem: ***For my javascript version, from what I have seen on the web, I am trying to use `setTimeout` `clearTimeout` functions to simulate sleep.*** because you cannot simulate `sleep()` in that way.  The JS function simply work differently (they are asynchronous, not synchronous).  If you describe what behavior you're actually trying to accomplish (from a high level) rather than making us try to figure it out from your non-working code, we might be able to suggest a code structure that could do that.

Comment: Oh, and please describe the problem your trying to solve/implement, not issues with your attempted solution.  We need to understand the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that one of this conditions is met? You can add `return;` at the end of the drawPath() function to get sure, that it gets back to the main function.